# Recommended Vim plugins for Java coding?

Tags: java, vim, vim-plugin

Are there any other plugins except for javacomplete javabrowser?

It has to support:

- auto import
- getter/setter maker
- global refactoring, change file/class/method name

Answer (score 3):

Came across Eclim recently with best of both the worlds, eclipse and vim. I personally feel Eclipse is the best IDE for java development.

- [Eclim](http://eclim.org/)
- [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/)

Comment: I'm using eclipse. It somehow changes my attitude towards IDE. But I like Vim .Eclim looks quite cool. Thank you!

Comment: Keep using a screwdriver to hammer in that nail...